# Why does spirv-remap give different outputs depending on out variable name?

Tags: spir-v

I'm trying to understand what spirv-remap does, so I created a simple fragment shader with a simple `layout(location=0) out vec4 fragColor;`, compiled with `glslang -V shader.frag -o shader.frag.spv` and then `spirv-remap --do-everything -i shader.frag.spv -o finalSpirV`. As expected, changing variable names inside a uniform block does not change the final data in `finalSpirV`, after all, it's just data and offsets. To my surprise, renaming `fragColor` changed it. I thought that variable name was completely internal to the shader, and meaningless to the "outside world". What is my misunderstanding about spirv and spirv-remap?

Example:

`shader1.frag`

```c
#version 460
layout(location=0) out vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

`shader2.frag`

```c
#version 460
layout(location=0) out vec4 outout;
void main()
{
    outout = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

after running `glslang -V shader1.frag -o shader1.frag.spv && spirv-remap --do-everything -i shader1.frag.spv -o finalSpirV1`, `glslang -V shader2.frag -o shader2.frag.spv && spirv-remap --do-everything -i shader2.frag.spv -o finalSpirV2`, `spirv-dis finalSpirV1 -o orgFrag1.frag` and `spirv-dis finalSpirV2 -o orgFrag2.frag` gives:

`orgFrag1.frag`

```
; SPIR-V
; Version: 1.0
; Generator: Khronos Glslang Reference Front End; 11
; Bound: 9012
; Schema: 0
               OpCapability Shader
          %1 = OpExtInstImport "GLSL.std.450"
               OpMemoryModel Logical GLSL450
               OpEntryPoint Fragment %5663 "main" %3647
               OpExecutionMode %5663 OriginUpperLeft
               OpDecorate %3647 Location 0
       %void = OpTypeVoid
       %1282 = OpTypeFunction %void
      %float = OpTypeFloat 32
    %v4float = OpTypeVector %float 4
%_ptr_Output_v4float = OpTypePointer Output %v4float
       %3647 = OpVariable %_ptr_Output_v4float Output
    %float_1 = OpConstant %float 1
    %float_0 = OpConstant %float 0
       %1416 = OpConstantComposite %v4float %float_1 %float_0 %float_0 %float_1
       %5663 = OpFunction %void None %1282
       %9011 = OpLabel
               OpStore %3647 %1416
               OpReturn
               OpFunctionEnd
```

`orgFrag2.frag`

```
; SPIR-V
; Version: 1.0
; Generator: Khronos Glslang Reference Front End; 11
; Bound: 9012
; Schema: 0
               OpCapability Shader
          %1 = OpExtInstImport "GLSL.std.450"
               OpMemoryModel Logical GLSL450
               OpEntryPoint Fragment %5663 "main" %3067
               OpExecutionMode %5663 OriginUpperLeft
               OpDecorate %3067 Location 0
       %void = OpTypeVoid
       %1282 = OpTypeFunction %void
      %float = OpTypeFloat 32
    %v4float = OpTypeVector %float 4
%_ptr_Output_v4float = OpTypePointer Output %v4float
       %3067 = OpVariable %_ptr_Output_v4float Output
    %float_1 = OpConstant %float 1
    %float_0 = OpConstant %float 0
       %1416 = OpConstantComposite %v4float %float_1 %float_0 %float_0 %float_1
       %5663 = OpFunction %void None %1282
       %9011 = OpLabel
               OpStore %3067 %1416
               OpReturn
               OpFunctionEnd
```

Cleary some id differs. Maybe SPIRV specification requires unique identifiers for out variables, and `spirv-remap` uses some kind of hash on the string name instead of a (more reasonable) sequential assignment of internal ids?

Comment: "*renaming fragColor changed it*" Changed *what*?

Comment: changed the binary output in the file finalSpirV

Comment: In what way was it changed?

Comment: From manual inspection, I think a sequence of 2 bytes that repeated in 3 places changed

Comment: What do you see when you disassemble the SPIR-V?

Comment: how do I disassemble it

Comment: ok, I downloaded `spirv-dis` and will complement now the question

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is indeed the ID remapping, which I can't find much documentation about. Running `spirv-remap` only with flags `--dce all --opt all --strip all` gives consistent outputs.

I still don't understand what's possibly the benefit of ID remapping, maybe someone can explain in the comments.

Comment: Apparently, if I don't remap ids, sometimes I get linker errors because some blocks with same name get different locations, so I will just stick to --do-everything

Answer (score 0):

Result IDs in SPIR-V are arbitrary; much like names in most programming languages, they are just placeholders. As such, a compiler can generate these IDs however they like. Compilers are in no way required to generate the same result IDs if you give it code that is only different based on the names.

Essentially, you cannot assume that if two SPIR-V binaries are un-equal, that they represent different shaders.

Comment: do you know how spirv-remap chooses these ids or if there is any documentation on it?

Comment: @Powereleven: What would it matter? IDs are fungible, irrelevant to the behavior of SPIR-V. As such, anything looking at SPIR-V should not rely on any particular ID generation algorithm. What are you trying to do such that you *need* IDs to be generated in a particular way?

Comment: just curiosity and I'm afraid ids may clash depending on shaders with attributes with same name but different order

Comment: @Powereleven: The latter would only matter if you're linking multiple SPIR-V binaries together into the same shader stage. For inter-stage shaders, variables are always connected by resource indices (locations/bindings), not by names or result IDs. And resource indices in SPIR-V are required to be explicitly specified.

Comment: @Powereleven: Also, apparently neither OpenGL nor Vulkan allows linking multiple SPIR-V binaries together in the same shader stage within their APIs. So if you want to do that, it's up to you to combine their SPIR-V results together and aggregate any commonalities between them.